# XMLGregorianCalendar not showing time values

Tags: java, date

Two different Linux machines and two different Java behavior

1) (the proper one I think) YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 2015-09-22T17:10:30.45+01:00)

2) YYYY-MM-DDTZD (eg 2015-09-22+00:02)

Is it possible that JVM version or Locale settings on a linux machine influence XMLGregorianCalendar.toString() results? If not, what could be?

Comment: No. The Javadoc shows exactly what the resulting value of `XMLGregorianCalendar#toString` will look like. You're seeing something else.

Comment: @sotirios-delimanolis I'm reading the Javadoc... toString()' result is a lexical representation generated by toXMLFormat(). This last one uses the getXMLSchemaType()  that return the name of the XML Schema date/time type that this instance maps to. Type is computed based on fields that are set. So I have to assume that time fields are not valorized?

Comment: That seems like a fair hypothesis and easy to test!